# jquery strange flickering on mouseover/out

Tags: javascript, jquery

The HTML:

```
<div id="timerList">
...
    <li rel="project" class="open">
        <a class="" style="" href=""><ins>&nbsp;</ins>Project C</a>
    </li>
...
</div>
```

The javascript/jquery:

```
$('#timerList li[rel="project"]').mouseover(function(){
    $('a:first',this).after('<span class="addNew"><a href="#">Add Timer</a></span>');
}).mouseout(function(){
    $('.addNew',this).remove();
});
```

When I hover my mouse over an li element, a span.addNew element is created within

THE PROBLEM:
When I put my mouse ofer the span.addNew, it flickers on and off.  Perhaps the mouseout event is firing, but I don't understand why it would or how to prevent it.

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the [`.hover()`](http://api.jquery.com/hover/) function, like this:

```
$('#timerList li[rel="project"]').hover(function(){
    $('a:first',this).after('<span class="addNew"><a href="#">Add Timer</a></span>');
}, function(){
    $('.addNew',this).remove();
});
```

[`.hover()`](http://api.jquery.com/hover/) is the same as using [`.mouseenter()`](http://api.jquery.com/mouseenter/) and [`.mouseleave()`](http://api.jquery.com/mouseleave/).  The `mouseover` and `mouseout` events fire when entering a child element, using `mouseenter` and `mouseleave` doesn't do this, eliminating the flicker, caused by removing and adding the span.

[You can read more about the differences here](http://api.jquery.com/mouseenter/):

> The `mouseenter` event differs from `mouseover` in the way it handles event bubbling. If `mouseover` were used in this example, then when the mouse pointer moved over the Inner element, the handler would be triggered. This is usually undesirable behavior. The `mouseenter` event, on the other hand, only triggers its handler when the mouse enters the element it is bound to, not a descendant. So in this example, the handler is triggered when the mouse enters the Outer element, but not the Inner element.

Answer (score 0):

It's probably happening because jquery doesn't know that your new element is part of the DOM and thus doesn't recognize the mouseover. I'm not sure, but you might need jquery's [live](http://api.jquery.com/live/) in this case.

Alternatively, instead of creating this element and then deleting it, you might want to create it up front but set display:none. Then hide / unhide the element.